# What is the password to the keypad in the secret office in sister location?

Tags: fnaf-sister-location

There is a keypad in the secret office. In the secret office is 2 doors, 1 vent, 3 tv's, 1 poster, and 1 keypad.

Answer (score 0):

### Fnaf Sister Location Keycode

The bite of '83 is the code if you follow the lore. The code 1983 unlocks the three monitors on the desk. These monitors show direct camera feed footage of the Fnaf 4 location.